# "called" vs. "named" vs. "namely"

Tags: difference, word-difference

I wrote

> In particular, we use textual delimiters and identifiable constants or patterns within the content, **named anchors**, to recognize a data region, which is a node of the DOM tree enclosing the region.

*Anchor* is the term I devised, now should I use "called", "named", "namely"... for it? What would be the difference?

Comment: Take a look at [***namely***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/namely). If you check the definition and example sentence (along with other examples), I think you can figure this out.

Comment: Rather than trying to do this in a single word, you should consider using a phrase: _We use textual delimiters and identifiable constants or patterns within the content, which we will call **anchors_.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to do this in a single word, you should consider using a phrase:

> *We use textual delimiters and identifiable constants or patterns within the content, which we will call **anchors***.

In addition to "which we will call X," there are a few other regularly-used expressions in English, which I will call *name identifiers*. Other name identifiers include:

- *...which we have named **anchors**.*
- *...henceforth referred to as **anchors**.*

As an example, a 1970 U.S. Federal Regulation on Agriculture says:

> Four of the members and their alternates shall be producers or officers or employees of producers, henceforth referred to as "producer members" of the committee.